# SSRS convert negative and positive seconds to hours and mins

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, reporting

I've a SSRS report and need to convert seconds to hours and mins.  The values have both negative and positive numbers and some of them are over 24hrs, I found the following query and it helps but doesn't display over 24hrs.

Name | ID | VT
---- | -- | ------
abc  | 1  | -633600.000000

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)=0,"0:00",
 IIF(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)< 0,"-"&Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)), "00:00"), "HH:mm"),
 Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)), "00:00"), "HH:mm")))
```

Name | ID | VT
---- | -- | ------
abc  | 1  | -16:00

it should show
Name | ID | VT
---- | -- | ------
abc  | 1  | -176:00

I tried to rewrite the above to the following and I get Syntax Error, (it says i don't have false defined)

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)=0,"0:00",
 IIF(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)< 86400,"-"&Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)), "00:00"), "HH:mm"), 
    Floor(Fields!VT.Value / 86400) & " days, " & Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)), "00:00"), "HH:mm")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need 2 more closing parenthesis at the end.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  Thank you!  that was it, my syntax is correct now, but the desired result i didn't get.  I'll keep at it to see if i get desired result

Answer (score 1):

I think i've got it!

> =IIF(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)=0,"0:00",  Floor(SUM(Fields!VT.Value) /
>   3600) &":"&Format(DateAdd("s",ABS(SUM(Fields!VT.Value)), "00:00"),
>   "mm:ss"))

that is giving me the result I need.